# How to restrict proportional editing of vertices to an edge loop?

Tags: edit-mode, vertices

I am trying to model a fat guy and need to adjust an edge loop to better fit around his gut. I want to use proportional editing but only have it affect vertices on the edge loop. How can this be done? This is not the most pressing example but I will require smoother adjustments soon.
[image: Need to drag out front vertex with falloff to near vertices in same loop]

Answer (score 3):

Select your edge loop, <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>H</kbd> to hide the other vertices, then play with your edge loop, and when you have finished, <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>H</kbd> to make visible again.

Comment: Instead of selecting, Ctrl I then H to hide the "other mesh", simply select your edge loop and hit Shift H to hide unselected mesh.

Comment: yes of course you're right  ;)